How to use constants inside Amp\parallelMap in PHP?
I need some help with using global constants inside amp\parallelMap. I have a bootstrap file that I require_once in my project, where I define global constants like MAX_DATA.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
$pool = new DefaultPool(self::THREAD_COUNT);

$results = wait(parallelMap($data, function ($point) {
   return $this->reCalc($point); // some time-intensive task
}, $pool));


The reCalc method requires access to the global constant MAX_DATA, but I am unable to access it inside the closure passed to parallelMap. I get an error "Undefined constant MAX_DATA".
The only solution I found is to define the constant again within the closure, or to include the bootstrap file again:
$max = MAX_DATA;

$pool = new DefaultPool(self::THREAD_COUNT);

$results = wait(parallelMap($data, function ($point) use ($max) {
   if (!defined('MAX_DATA')) define('MAX_DATA', $max);
   
   return $this->reCalc($point); // some time-intensive task
}, $pool));


Is there a better way to access global constants inside the closure passed to parallelMap without redefining them?

I'm having trouble reproducing - using a minimal test case: define('MAX_DATA', 123); $fn = function () { var_dump(defined('MAX_DATA')); }; $fn(); shows bool(true).  Is there some other process control logic happening inside parallelMap() or wait()? Update - ah, just read up about Amp\ParallelMap, which is all about processing in another thread

Indeed, ParallelMap spawns new process that doesn’t inherit the environment of the parent process, including any constants. require_once() or define() inside the closure does  make the trick, but looks messy.
